# Android ACTION_DIAL

Tags: android

I have this line of code inside should OverrideUrlLoading method

```
   if(url.startsWith("tel:")){
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Call"));
       return true;
    }
```

Everything is working fine not until a user reported that when she clicked on the telephone number it opens in the phone dialer but with `\\\\` in the beginning. The user is using htc sensation device. I just want to know why there's a `\\\\`. 
Haven't encountered this on samsung desire, samsung s3, and htc one.

Comment: you'd have to know what is the url that was clicked. apparently it would be of the form `tel://555` rather than `tel:555`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could have a look at the content of the url?
I just guess not sure.